# Changing custom cell appearance when entering editing mode

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I have a table with custom cells, that I built in IB. When entering editing mode, content of all cells is moved to show delete edit control. My question is where can I adjust the cell appearance before entering editing mode? I saw that willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath function is supposed to let adjust the UI, but seems I don't get there at all.

Please help,

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` has following functions for adjusting its contents when cell's state is changing:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
- (void)didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
```

So you can subclass `UITableViewCell` and override those function in it to adjust cell's appearance.

Comment: Thanks! This + layout views gave the perfect results!